# assert function could not be resolved in eclipse c++

Tags: c++, assert

guys! I am trying to do some test functions using assertions:

test.h

```
#include <assert.h>

void testTheMedicine(){
    Medicine m = Medicine(1, "para", 30, 40);
    assert(m.getName()="para");// Function 'assert' could not be resolved

}
```

Why am I getting that error? I am using Eclipse for C++

Comment: Assert isn't actually a function. It can't be, because it relies on actual text replacement. You should also use `Medicine m(1, "para", 30, 40);` and `m.getName() == "para"` (assuming `std::string` or similar).

Answer (score 3):

This is not how you compare Strings in C++.

Instead of the `=` operator, you should use `==`:

`m.getName()="para"` should be `m.getName() == "para"`

Comment: Only if it returns a C string. In C++, you compare strings using ==. That has nothing to do with the error, though.